# I would like to link my sub domain hosted in 1&1 to my application hosted in OVH on my VPS

Tags: redirect, server, hosting, vps

I have a main website hosted in 1&1 and I have an web application in OVH VPS.
I create a sub domain app.mydomain.com in 1&1 and I did a redirection from my sub domain to the IP of my OVH VPS.

When I enter my sub domain app.mydomain.com it go to my OVH VPS but it show the IP Address. There is a way to not show this ip address?
Should I do any configuration on my OVH VPS? I do not want to transfer my sub domain as I have my website host on 1&1.
I tried to create Type A on 1&1 and map to the IP Address of OVH VPS but it is not working (I put ttl 1 minute). After 10 minutes I could see any changes.

I am a bit lost.

Regards,

Let me know if you have any solutions.

Comment: Anyone did something similar?

Comment: solved: I redirect type A sub.domain.com from 1&1 to OVH VPS IP and CNAME sub.domain.com from 1&1 to Hostname from VPS OVH